# Fetch steam json inventory

Tags: php, json, steam, inventory

So I've got a this code:

```
$user['steamid'] = "76561198350584156";
$inv = curl('https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/'.$user['steamid'].'/730/2?
l=english&count=5000');
$inv = json_decode($inv, true);
```

And i've got a response, something like:

```
Array
(
  [assets] => Array
  (
  [0] => Array
   (
     [classid] => 1989373359
   )
  )
 [descriptions] => Array
 (
  [0] => Array
  (
    [classid] => 1989373359
  )
 )
)
```

And there is arrays from [0] to for example [5], and how can i need to check if one classid from assets = classid from descriptions, how can i check it? I'm doing foreach (I want to list all of this items), but i need this classid from assets and from descriptions.

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script I made a while ago:

```
            $items = $data["rgDescriptions"];

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $image_url = "http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/";

            if($item["icon_url_large"]) {
                $image_url = $item["icon_url_large"];
            } else {
                $image_url = $item["icon_url"];
            }

            $hash = str_replace("+", "%20", urlencode($item["market_hash_name"]));
            if(substr($item["name"], 0, 4) == "Stat") echo " stattrack ";
            echo $item["name"];
            echo "<img src='http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/" . $image_url . " ' height='42' width='42'/>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, but you are using old API which have higher limits, (2 requests per second)?

Comment: The solution to your problem is : $data = json_decode($json, true);

Comment: Then you can just var_dump($data) and see what you have

Comment: And what are you trying to get?

Comment: And im trying to get each classid from assets, and from descriptions im trying to get i.e icon_url where descriptions['classid'] is equal to assets['classid']

Comment: The script I posted, has it. Check it out